# Android custom picker?

Tags: android, picker

[image]

I'd like to implement this kind of picker but instead of numbers, I can pick images or any kind of view. Is this possible?

Comment: You are welcome to do what you want. There is no `ImageOrAnyKindOfViewPicker`, though, so you will need to implement it yourself. For example, you could look at the source to `NumberPicker`, which IIRC is what `DatePicker` is using for its components.

Comment: I just thought there might be a view I'm not aware of that does exactly what I need. For now I'll look to customize NumberPicker, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Anything is possible, but not everything is easy. ;)   You will have to create these widgets yourself. Here's some starting points:

- [TimePicker](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/widget/TimePicker.java) source
- TimePickers are made up of [NumberPickers](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/com/android/internal/widget/NumberPicker.java)
- NumberPickers contain [NumberPickerButtons](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/com/android/internal/widget/NumberPickerButton.java)

Creating your own copies of these would be a solid starting point; from there you can branch out the content types you want to support. When it's done, be sure to release it as an open source library. ;)